# How to pass OR condition from Query part of Url (Rest Api)

Tags: mysql, rest, api

I really struggling to find the solution for passing OR condition in the Query part of URL. Could someone please resolve it.

Example: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1&email=Eliseo@gardner.biz

The above query gives the result for AND Condition. In the same way, I am looking for OR condition.

Comment: You could add a parameter like `&op=or` that tells the `comments` script to use `OR` instead of `AND` when it's constructing the query.

Answer (score -1):

```
GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1&email=Eliseo@gardner.biz
```

> The above query gives the result for AND Condition.

No it doesn't.  It returns a representation of the resource identified by `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1&email=Eliseo@gardner.biz`

The server can, at its discretion, treat the query part as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, in which case it can be interpreted as a set of key/value pairs.

The implementation is allowed to do anything that it likes with those keys and values.

```
/c5dc7cb4-2491-4bb5-91ac-36c104f3bb07?postId=1&email=Eliseo@gardner.biz
/f42cbf5b-178a-4b46-8860-bffff3509341?postId=1&email=Eliseo@gardner.biz
```

As far as REST is concerned, it is perfectly fine that one of those is an "AND" query and the other is an "OR" query.